# Problem on obfuscating j2me applications in Netbeans 6.8

Tags: java-me, obfuscation, netbeans6.8, proguard

When I'm trying to package a midlet with obfuscation, the following is displayed on the output window:

```
pre-init:
pre-load-properties:
exists.config.active:
exists.netbeans.user:
exists.user.properties.file:
load-properties:
exists.platform.active:
exists.platform.configuration:
exists.platform.profile:
basic-init:
cldc-pre-init:
cldc-init:
cdc-init:
ricoh-pre-init:
ricoh-init:
semc-pre-init:
semc-init:
savaje-pre-init:
savaje-init:
sjmc-pre-init:
sjmc-init:
cdc-hi-pre-init:
cdc-hi-init:
nokiaS80-pre-init:
nokiaS80-init:
nsicom-pre-init:
nsicom-init:
post-init:
init:
conditional-clean-init:
conditional-clean:
deps-jar:
pre-preprocess:
do-preprocess:
Pre-processing 0 file(s) into C:\Meljean's Files\NetBeansProjects\SampleApp\build\preprocessed directory.
post-preprocess:
preprocess:
pre-compile:
extract-libs:
Expanding: C:\Meljean's Files\LWUIT_1_4\lib\LWUIT.jar into C:\Meljean's Files\NetBeansProjects\SampleApp\build\compiled
do-compile:
post-compile:
compile:
pre-obfuscate:
proguard-init:
skip-obfuscation:
proguard:
Error: Expecting class path separator ';' before 's' in argument number 4
C:\Meljean's Files\NetBeansProjects\SampleApp\nbproject\build-impl.xml:427: Obfuscation failed with error code 1.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

What am I going to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem might be in the WTK's installation dir.

Lets confirm this:

I guess you are using WIN SYSTEM

I guess your WTK is installed at the path where space comes inbetween.

like for ex : c:\program files\  [space between program & files]

I would suggest you to install WTK on non space dir like **c:\WTK**

Let me know if this is not the case.

Comment: I'm not using WTK.  I'm using Netbeans' Mobility pack.  But I'm using Windows. Netbeans is installed in Program Files.

Comment: Internally Netbeans uses WTK only, download WTK from oracle site and install directly on C:\ and configure your project to refer to that WTK, it should work

Comment: By the way, I'm using Samsung SDK as the project's emulator platform and I'm not using WTK.  But the SDK that I'm using is not installed in Program Files but in a different directory without spaces.

Comment: can you post whole log which is generated while obfuscation.

Comment: @jean27 i am not sure but lets try by renaming Meljean's Files to MeljeanFiles.